# Dollar sign is not displayed correctly with decimal.ToString("C", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Tags: c#, .net-core, globalization

I don't like asking such a small problem, but I found nothing and have no clue, why it's acting like this...

In one of my WebAPI (.NET Core) projects I have declared the following very simple method.

```
private static string GetDiffText(decimal diff)
{
    var abs = Math.Abs(diff);
    string diffText;

    var absoluteValue = abs.ToString("C", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (diff >= 0)
    {
        diffText = $"+{absoluteValue}";
    }
    else
    {
        diffText = $"-{absoluteValue}";
    }
    return diffText;
}
```

The results of the ToString()-line should be: $23.59

But it actually looks like this:

[image: Dollar sign not recognised]

Whats weird about it: When I use my default culture (which is €), the Euro-sign is correctly. So why does the dollar sign make such problems?

Comment: What do you expect the InvariantCulture's symbol to be?

Comment: @RichardSchneider I would expect it to display $23.59? Is that not what InvariantCuliture should do?

Comment: Wrong.  The invariant currency symbol is `¤`'.

Comment: Ohhh, wow, I didn't know that, thank you for the duplicate-link.

Comment: Btw, you *can* use format specifiers within interpolated strings: `$"+{abs:C}"` although it'll use current culture, not invariant. You can use `FormattableString.Invariant($"+{abs:C}")` if you needed invariant culture

Comment: I didn't know that thank you :) I solved the issue by defining the culture I needed and using it inside string.Format :)